# UK visitor visa on F1-OPT (STEM) - Need help with travel history

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I really need some help filling up the form for the UK visitor visa.

A quick background:

1. Came to the US from India in August 2019 on an F1 visa
2. Travelled to India in October 2020 for 3 weeks, and reentered the US the same month.
3. In July 2021, got my initial OPT.
4. Visited India in March 2022 for 2 weeks, and reentered the same month on F1-OPT.
5. Got my STEM extension OPT in July 2022, and currently in the US on F1-OPT (stem extension) which expires in July 2024.

In the section for travel history to the US, I'm not quite sure what to put there. It asks for the details of the last two travels.

1. For the last travel - Under "how long was your travel (months/years)" - should I put the number of months until my F1 visa expires? Also, I am on F1-OPT (stem) working for a company, so is my purpose to study or work? Practically, F1 is still considered a study visa.
2. For the second last travel, I have an entry date in October 2020 and a fixed length of travel (17 months until I left to travel to India). But my status changed from F1 to F1-OPT. Same conundrum as the last one - should I say study or work for my purpose?

I'd really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: You have been legally resident in the US since 2019 (and presumably are applying from there). I’d say the travel history you need to include in your application is the two trips to India. Does the UK visitor visa application specifically ask about travel to the US, not just travel in general?

Comment: @Traveller thanks for replying. Yes, I'm applying from the US. It asks for travel history specifically for the following countries -
Australia, Canada, New Zealand, USA, Switzerland, European Economic Area (do not include travel to the UK).


I did mention earlier in the application that I'm a resident in the US right now, so you're right to say that my travel is to India if anything. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I want to know how did your whole process go with UK visa from the US being on F1. Can you please let me know. I'm about to do the same process and incidentally we have the exactly same travel history to US, so I'm sure it'll be helpful.